# disable message signing from service to client

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, c#-4.0, x509certificate

How can I disable message signing from Service to Client(s)? 
I'm using basicHttpBinding with **Message** security mode and **Certificates** as credential type.

I have working solution, but this solution use certificate signing in both direction; I want to require only direction Client -> Service. How can I achieve it? Is it even possible?
My usecase is pretty easy; basically I don't want to require from clients to specify service certificate, they just provide theirs certificate and I just in my custom certificate validator check if this certificate is registred and enabled...

Service configuration

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="MyApp.ServiceBehavior" name="MyApp.Service">
      <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MyApp.IService" bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding">
        <identity>
          <dns value="SebastianServer" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
    </service>
  </services>

  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="MyApp.ServiceBehavior">
        <serviceCredentials>
          <serviceCertificate findValue="052026af9ea372c95b63acc3fb9f36859931f205" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="My" />

          <clientCertificate>
            <!--<authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerOrChainTrust" revocationMode="NoCheck" />-->
            <authentication certificateValidationMode="Custom" customCertificateValidatorType="MyApp.CustomValidator, MyApp"/>
          </clientCertificate>

        </serviceCredentials>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>

  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="CustomBinding">
        <security mode="Message">
          <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
        </security>
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Client config

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="certificateEndpoint">
        <clientCredentials>
          <clientCertificate findValue="f2ba8e5a7531df7097117661d966d1f14fccb360" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="My" />
          <serviceCertificate>
            <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerOrChainTrust" revocationMode="NoCheck" />
            <defaultCertificate findValue="052026af9ea372c95b63acc3fb9f36859931f205" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="My" />
          </serviceCertificate>
        </clientCredentials>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>

  <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService">
          <security mode="Message">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>

  <client>
    <endpoint
      address="http://localhost:5129/Service.svc"
      binding="basicHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService"
      contract="MyAppService.IService"
      behaviorConfiguration="certificateEndpoint"
      name="BasicHttpBinding_IService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="SebastianServer"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
  </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible with Custum binding.